# How to check core dump inside a podman container?

Tags: podman

redirect core dump to /ap_core directory for sharing later

```
mkdir -p /ap_core && chmod 1777 /ap_core
cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
echo '/ap_core/core.t%t.u%u.s%s.p%p.%e' > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
ls -alZ /ap_core
  drwxrwxrwt.  2 root root unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0     15 Sep  5 10:10 .
  dr-xr-xr-x. 19 root root system_u:object_r:root_t:s0           253 Jun 19 15:20 ..
```

start the container

```
podman run --rm -i -t -v /ap_core:/ap_core:z ubi8/ubi-micro
sh-4.4# ls -al /ap_core
ls: cannot open directory '/ap_core': Permission denied
sh-4.4# ls -alZd /ap_core
drwxrwxrwt. 2 nobody nobody unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0 15 Sep  5 02:10 /ap_core
```

Answer (score 0):

add this option `--security-opt label=disable` and the `:z` is not necessary.

```
podman run --rm -i -t --security-opt label=disable -v /ap_core:/ap_core ubi8/ubi-micro
```